# Monitor file size when writing file using a BufferedWriter in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a potentially long list of items to a file. The items I'm writing are of variable length. If the file size produced is greater than 10M it should be broken up into multiple files. To aid performance I'm currently using a BufferedWriter as below:

```
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
final OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osr);
```

By doing this though I'm not able accurately monitor the size of the file I'm writing. I could flush this often or remove it, but of course that would have a performance impact. What's the best option for this? Ideally I'd like to get the sizes of the files produced as close to the 10M mark as possible.

Comment: What are you using to write? `write` and `newLine`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, don't use a `BufferedWriter` but a simple `FileOutputStream` (which you have already). Write (and check the size of) your string's `.getBytes("UTF-8")`. You may have to write additional newlines if needed though, but that's simple enough.

This way you can know by advance the size you have to write.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses Java 7's `try`-with-resources statement; if you're targeting an earlier platform you'll have to manually close the streams.

```
final int MAX_BYTES = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
final int NEWLINE_BYTES = System.getProperty("line.separator")
                                .getBytes("UTF-8").length;
int bytesWritten = 0;
int fileIndex = 0;
while (existsMoreData()) {
    try (
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            getFileNameForIndex(fileIndex));
         OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osr)) {

        String toWrite = getCurrentStringToWrite();
        int bytesOfString = toWrite.getBytes("UTF-8").length;
        if (bytesWritten + bytesOfString + NEWLINE_BYTES > MAX_BYTES
         || bytesWritten == 0 /* if this part > MAX_BYTES */ ) {

            // need to start a new file
            fileIndex++;
            bytesWritten = 0;
            continue; // auto-closed because of try-with-resources
        } else {
            bw.write(toWrite, 0, toWrite.length());
            bw.newLine();
            bytesWritten += bytesOfString + NEWLINE_BYTES;
            incrementDataToWrite();
        }

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Possible implementations:

```
String[] data = someLongString.split("\n");
int currentPart = 0;

private boolean existsMoreData() {
    return currentPart + 1 < data.length;
}

private String getCurrentStringToWrite() {
    return data[currentPart];
}

private void incrementDataToWrite() {
    currentPart++;
}

private String getFileNameForIndex(int index) {
    final String BASE_NAME = "/home/codebuddy/somefile";
    return String.format("%s_%s.txt", BASE_NAME, index);
    // equivalent to:
 // return BASE_NAME + "_" + index + ".txt";
}
```