# How to get writing status of workbook.write()

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, fileoutputstream, sxssf

we are working on project where we have to write millions of data by workbook SXSSF and workbook.write method taking very long time to come out.

```
fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\asd.xlsx");  
wbs.write(fos); //wbs is SXSSFWorkbook object
```

I just want some way by which I can show some status while wbs.write(fos) is on call, like percentage being  written or anything which give some status.

Comment: There's no support for that kind of functionality in `SXSSFWorkBook`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012978/monitor-file-size-when-writing-file-using-a-bufferedwriter-in-java